# How to change an object property directly with an ArrayAdapter ? (Listview)

Tags: android, listview

I am using a listview with an arrayadapter.. and i wish to know how to change an object property directly with an adapter ? without having to remove it and readding it. It is possible ?

Currently i use ..

```
    btnModifierNom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){            
               @Override            
               public void onClick(View v) {
                    int itemPosition = lstPersonnes.getCheckedItemPosition();
                    selectedItem = lstPersonnes.getItemAtPosition(itemPosition).toString();

                    String personne = adapter.getItem(itemPosition);

                    adapter.remove(personne);
                    personne = txtNouveauNom.getText().toString();
                    adapter.insert(personne, itemPosition);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();             }
            });
```

But its not a very elegant way.. if possible i would love to avoid removing it and reinserting it.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, this is the best approach, simple and cheap. Right usage of adapter.

Comment: Seriously ? we can't just take the reference and modify it ? well i tried but it didn't work so i suppose your right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just change the value like this:

```
int itemPosition = lstPersonnes.getCheckedItemPosition();
String personne = adapter.getItem(itemPosition);
personne = txtNouveauNom.getText().toString();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And if `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` didn't work with this, then try `listView1.setAdapter(adapter)` to refresh the listview.

**UPDATE:**

Try this:

```
btnModifierNom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{            
    @Override            
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int itemPosition = lstPersonnes.getCheckedItemPosition();            
        // Gets the textview of the item at the position in the listview
        ((TextView)lstPersonnes.getChildAt(itemPosition)).setText(txtNouveauNom.getText().toString());

        // Put this
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // Or this to refresh listview
        lstPersonnes.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried and it doesnt work lol Actually that what i would have done.. but the list doesnt get updated with the new name.

Comment: You tried, `listView1.setAdapter(adapter)`? If yes, can you show me your getItem() and getView() function in your custom list adapter? It's strange if this doesn't work, since I have done this before and it works.

Comment: Tried too.. all it do is remove selection nothing else. Btw. I don't have a custom list adapter.. i use the ArrayAdapter only. Its a list of string.

Comment: Oh. Check the update. In this case, the lstPersonnes.setAdapter(adapter) will probably work to refresh the listview, but you could try using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to see if that works too.

Comment: It work but not expected results. as soon as i selected something else.. it reset to original list. that is without adapter.notifyDataSetChanged and without setAdapter.. but i use setAdapter or notify alone it doesnt work. I figured out that if i use maListePrenoms.set(itemPosition, personne); and then reset the adapter.. it work but i lost selection which is not what i want. Maybe the best solution is to make a class derived on BaseAdapter ? What your opinion ?

Comment: It would be better if you make your own class extending BaseAdapter. Then you would have control over the layout of the items as well as some of the background processing of making the listview. Also, I realized why the refresh didn't work. Since the listview items' values are from a list of strings you passed on, you needed to change the value of the string in the specified position and not the textview. That way, when you call listView1.setAdapter(adapter), the listview would change the value of the textview based on the string, when it goes through the list adapter's getView() function.

Comment: However, calling setAdapter will remove any selection done. So i will guess i will go the way of extending BaseAdapter and adding a set method there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Alright. This was the solution. Extending a class to baseadapter or arrayadapter and implement a method called set and it work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ArrayAdapter is intended for static data. Try extending from [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html), then notifyDataSetChanged() will work.